# Is a matrix whose quadrants obey eigenvalue restrictions positive semidefinite?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, semidefinite-programming

Suppose I have some Hermitian matrix $M$. Let $M = \begin{pmatrix} A & B\\B^* & D \end{pmatrix}$. Let $d = \dim(A) = \dim(B)$. Does the following hold?

If $\lambda_i(A)=\lambda_i(D) \geq \lambda_i(B) \text{ for all } i\in [d]$
Then: $A$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: What does $dim(A)$ or $dim(B)$ mean?  What are "quadrants" in this context, and are the $\lambda_i$ applications enumerating the  eigenvalues in some way?

Comment: Capital letters, $A,B,C,D$ denote matrices. $\dim(A)$ is the dimension of a matrix $A$. Since it is stated that $\dim(A) = \dim(B)$, the structure of $M$ is shown, AND it is stated than $M$ is Hermitian, this implies that $A,B,B^*,D$ are basically the for quadrants of $M$. If we think of $M$, a square matrix as a finite grid,  $A,B,B^*,D$ partition this grid into 4 blocks. I call them quadrants.

Comment: Further, $\lambda_i(A)$ for some matrix $A$ denotes the $i$-th eigenvalue of $A$, where order goes from greatest to smallest (note that all the eigenvalues of $A$ must be real since $A$ is Hermitian).

Comment: So, for the first part, you assume $A,B,B^*,D$ are each $d\times d$ complex(?) matrices.  For the second part, since $A,D$ are Hermitian, we know they have real eigenvalues, exactly $d$ of them counting multiplicity.  Unfortunately it is not clear what $\lambda_i(B)$ might mean.  Additional information is needed to show that $B$ has real eigenvalues, allowing the comparison you assert.

Comment: There seems to be a typo - do you want to conclude that $M$ is positive semidefinite?

Answer (score 0):

No it does not imply that $M$ is positive semidefinite.
Counter example:

Let $M = \begin{pmatrix} 2 &0 &3 &0 \\ 0& 4 &0& 0 \\ 3 &0 &2& 0 \\ 0 &0 &0 &4 \end{pmatrix}$
Then $M$ has a $-1$ eigenvalue.

Perhaps this holds only if the eigenvalues that have some over lap in their eigenvectors are bigger...